# Replace accents in csv reorder file with php

Tags: php, csv, replace, diacritics

I have a csv file that rearranges the columns of another csv via php.
I would like two columns to have no more special characters or accents after the reorder.
In my case, columns 21 and 22.
Here is my php file.

```
<?php
    $sInFile='in.csv';
    $sOutFile='out_'.date("YmdHis").'.csv';
    $iRow = 0;
    if( ( $rHandle = fopen( $sInFile, "r")) !== FALSE ) 
    {
        while( ( $aData = fgetcsv( $rHandle, 1000, ";") ) !== FALSE ) 
        {
            $iCountColumns = count( $aData );
            for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountColumns; ++$i )
            {
                $sTmp  = '';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 0 ];   
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 1 ];   
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 13 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 15 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 16 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 36 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 17 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 4 ];   
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 24 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 25 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 26 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 27 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 28 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 30 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 31 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 32 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 33 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 34 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 20 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 2 ];   
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 3 ];   
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 5 ];   
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 6 ];   
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 7 ];   
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 8 ];   
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 9 ];   
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 10 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 11 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 12 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 14 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 18 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 19 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 21 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 22 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 23 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 29 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 35 ];  
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 37 ];  
                $sTmp .= "\r";
                $sTmp .= "\n"; 
            }
            file_put_contents( $sOutFile, $sTmp, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );
        }
        ++$iRow;
    }
?>
```

I'm not sure if this is the right track but here is the function I want to use to replace the accents.

```
function replaceAccents($str) {
    $search = explode("ç,æ,œ,á,é,í,ó,ú,à,è,ì,ò,ù,ä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,â,ê,î,ô,û,å,ø,Ø,Å,Á,À,Â,Ä,È,É,Ê,Ë,Í,Î,Ï,Ì,Ò,Ó,Ô,Ö,Ú,Ù,Û,Ü,Ÿ,Ç,Æ,Œ");
    $replace = explode("c,ae,oe,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,y,a,e,i,o,u,a,o,O,A,A,A,A,A,E,E,E,E,I,I,I,I,O,O,O,O,U,U,U,U,Y,C,AE,OE");
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
}
```

I'm a little confused as to how to get the function taken into account when reordering.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed a little rest to find the answer :)
Here is the solution if it can help someone else.

My need was to remove the accents on only two columns of my csv after reorder (for columns 21 and 22 in my case) and to keep the accents on the other columns.

```
<?php
function replaceAccents($str) {
    $search = explode(",","ç,æ,œ,á,é,í,ó,ú,à,è,ì,ò,ù,ä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,â,ê,î,ô,û,å,ø,Ø,Å,Á,À,Â,Ä,È,É,Ê,Ë,Í,Î,Ï,Ì,Ò,Ó,Ô,Ö,Ú,Ù,Û,Ü,Ÿ,Ç,Æ,Œ");
    $replace = explode(",","c,ae,oe,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,y,a,e,i,o,u,a,o,O,A,A,A,A,A,E,E,E,E,I,I,I,I,O,O,O,O,U,U,U,U,Y,C,AE,OE");
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
}
$sInFile='in.csv';
$sOutFile='out'.date("YmdHis").'.csv';
$iRow = 0;
if( ( $rHandle = fopen( $sInFile, "r")) !== FALSE ) 
{
    while( ( $aData = fgetcsv( $rHandle, 1000, ";") ) !== FALSE ) 
    {
        $iCountColumns = count( $aData );
        for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountColumns; ++$i )
        {
                $sTmp  = '';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 0 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 1 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 13 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 15 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 16 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 36 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 17 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 4 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 24 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 25 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 26 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 27 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 28 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 30 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 31 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 32 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 33 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 34 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 20 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 2 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 3 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 5 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 6 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 7 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 8 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 9 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 10 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 11 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 12 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 14 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 18 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 19 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= replaceAccents( $aData[21] );
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= replaceAccents( $aData[22] );
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 23 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 29 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 35 ];
                $sTmp .= ';';
                $sTmp .= $aData[ 37 ];
                $sTmp .= "\r";
                $sTmp .= "\n"; 
        }
        file_put_contents( $sOutFile, $sTmp, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );
    }
    ++$iRow;
}
?>
```